# Copy command using OID on Postgresql (Without reading a file from FS)

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, copy

So, here is the situation:

I have a client that uploads a csv to my application and i save it on a table using OID, then to process the data i create a temporary table from the CSV and distribute the data i want to another tables, it works perfectly fine. But i really don't want to save the csv first on the filesystem every time i want to process it, there's any way to use the file in the db to run the COPY command to a table? What i want is something like this:

```
COPY temp_table FROM loread(lo_open((SELECT csv_file_oid FROM files_table WHERE liberacao_base_id = 104), 262144), 1000000) WITH DELIMITER ; CSV HEADER;
```

Theres a way to do anything like that? I really must save the file on the filesystem to run the COPY command? It seems a lot of resource waste for me if i already have it on my database. Thanks in advance (and sorry for my bad english.)

Comment: Is it web application? If so then file is most likely is already saved on filesystem anyway in some temporary dir (this is how upload works). If not then you can use `STDIN` instead of file in `COPY` command ([PostgreSQL 9.5.1 Documentation: COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)).

Comment: yes it is a web application, but is not saved on the filesystem, it's saved into a OID that references a binary field on postgres table. That's not how  upload works at all, the client transfers binary data trought a post to the server that handles it the way it wants,you can save on the FS or keep the bytearraystream on the memory and save it on the database like my webapp, for instance my application is not allowed to save anything on the FS as a company policy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the foreign data wrappers? You can just create a "foreign" 
table. It's a table that behaves like a normal table, but in the background, everytime it gets queried reads its content from the the .csv file in the file system.

[Here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/file-fdw.html) the official extension and [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers) few more.

The official extension is very easy to use:

```
--create the extension
CREATE EXTENSION file_fdw;

--create the server
CREATE SERVER file_fdw_server FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_fdw;

--create the foreign table 
CREATE foreign table temp_table (
   id_field INTEGER
  ,value_field VARCHAR
) SERVER file_fdw_server
OPTIONS (
   format 'csv' 
  ,header 'true'
  ,filename '/path_to_file/file.csv'
  ,delimiter ';'
  ,null ''
);

--Query the table as a standard table
select * from temp_table where id_field > 10 limit 100;
```

Comment: so, the csv is saved inside the database, how to use this field instead a file on the file system?

Comment: The csv is not saved inside the database. The foreign table we have just created is an "empty" table with no content. Every time we query the foreign table, postgres will read the content of the table from the file in the file system.

Comment: you are not understanding what i trying to say, the data i must read (which   is an OID field with binary csv data) is saved on the database table, not on the filesystem so i cant use anything related to filename paths...